# White noise percussion resonating capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, low-pass

I'm breadboarding an analog drum module from some 70s schematics. Experimenting with noise filtering, I've achieved a cool "resonating" sound but the result is a bit too noisy for professional recording.

The responsible is the 330nF capacitor to ground just before the pre-amp. Can anyone help me reducing the noise keeping the resonant effect? And, why this passive RC configuration is resonating like in a synth cutoff with resonance filter?[image]

Comment: Please show an oscilloscope image of the signal.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one...

Comment: At audio frequencies, a sound card on just about any PC would be a starting point for any AC measurement before you get yourself a real oscilloscope.

Comment: How do you know that the 330nF cap is responsible?

Comment: @Entropy Empirically. Without the 1.5K resistor and the 330n cap the circuit sounds like an ordinary vintage snare drum. Then I've added these two components trying to get a "pinker" noise and everything changed :) A 100n is even more resonating, like when you push up the resonance pot on a synth filter.

Comment: I am curious why would you add a capacitor to the negative input of an inverting amplifier anyway? The point of that node is to be a virtual ground node due to feedback of the op-amp. Sure it might produce interesting effects, but as an unwanted side-effect instead of on purpose.

Comment: Adding that capacitor and resistor increases the noise gain of the op-amp and, this is usually regarded as something that is undesirable.

Comment: @Justme Yes, right. I was just messing around :) It was clear even to me - totally ignorant in electronics - that was related to the OpAmp. Anyway, the output is a lot more interesting than the usual vintage snare drum. Quite similar to the snare in She Drives Me Crazy by Fine Young Cannibals.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, that's the answer, thank you. A friend suggested me to add that 100 Ohm resistor in series, and that mitigated a bit the high freq noise.

Comment: @:stv do you want me to leave a formal answer that you can accept (normal procedure for stack exchange sites)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *@Andyaka Yes, that's the answer, thank you. A friend suggested me to
> add that 100 Ohm resistor in series, and that mitigated a bit the high
> freq noise.*

Consider the notes I've added to the picture below: -

[image]

So, if you ignore the input and the virtual ground, what you are left with is a noise source on the non-inverting input being amplified by 300,000 ÷ 100. That's R63/R60. This is why you get a lot of noise at the output.

Comment: Thank you very much